# php curl loop stops unexpectely in linux shell. is there word limit on linux for loop?

Tags: php, linux, loops

this maybe very newbie queestion.

my php loop is for 100 times, and the same code works on Windows XP cmd mode fine. However, the same php loop stops after exactly 3 times on Linux shell. (Amazon EC2)

The code output lots of characters (html tags etc) for one loop (like 5,000 chars)

is it because Linux stopping the php loop after so many characters in screen?

if so how do i unlimit this, so i can get 100 times full loop?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your code is stopped by the [time limit on the execution time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Comment: do you mean time limit for php script? I doubt it. i have 'set_time_limit(0);' in the script. The same code loops for 100 times and it doesn't on Linux machine.

Comment: im thinking it's Linux problem to be solved by using 'ulimit' or something, but i dont have much clue yet.

Comment: Besides exectution time, [memory limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) may also be of influence. You have set [ulimits](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit)? What is the output of `ulimit -a`?

Comment: I found the error. Thanks Legolas. I used require_once where I shouldve used require. I figured this out after I got all errors out. I'm so newbie. thanks.